# Qt5: подключение библиотек

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь написать простую программу, подключаю

```
 #include <QPushButton>
```

но пишет, что библиотека не найдена. 
Раньше было так же с

`#include <QApplication>`, но поменял на `#include <QCoreApplication>`
Искал в интернете нашел, что надо добавить

```
 QT += core gui
 greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Не помогает, что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Я сталкивался с такой проблемой. **Дело в том что в Qt 5 все виджеты переехали из модуля QtGui в новый модуль QtWidgets**.
По этому в проектном файле (заголовочный .pro) необходимо добавить модуль виджетов - примерно так:

```
QT += widgets
```

в место старого модуля (хотя его можно оставить )

```
QT += gui
```

А в исходных файлах заменить модуль QtGui на модуль QtWidgets.
Заменить строку :

```
 #include <QtGui>
```

на строку :

```
 #include <QtWidgets>
```

*В вашем случае  будет достаточно изменения только в проектного файла, но что бы развернуть ответ полностью я добавил пару строк.*

*Либо просто скопируйте и вставьте  :*

```
 QT += core gui widgets
 greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
```